# how to fix the function so that the resulting dataframe has only the subsetted column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**trying to subset a dataframe to remove/drop certain columns from a given dataframe**
*Please help me to fix this function*

```
dataframe = pd.DataFrame({
    "X": range(10),
    "Y": range(10,20),
    "Z": range(5,15)
})

def subset_dataframe(dataframe, drop_cols):
    subset_df = data.drop([drop_cols], inplace=True)
    return subset_df


subsetted_df = subset_dataframe(dataframe, drop_cols=["x", "z"])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dataframe = pd.DataFrame({ "X": range(10), "Y": range(10,20), "Z": range(5,15) })

def subset_dataframe(dataframe, drop_cols): subset_df = data.drop(columns = [drop_cols], inplace=True) return subset_df

subsetted_df = subset_dataframe(dataframe, drop_cols=["x", "z"])
```

add columns as well in data.drop($)

## EDIT 1:

final function:

```
dataframe = pd.DataFrame({ "X": range(10), "Y": range(10,20), "Z": range(5,15) })

def subset_dataframe(dataframe, drop_cols): 
    subset_df = dataframe.drop(columns = drop_cols) 
    return subset_df

subsetted_df = subset_dataframe(dataframe, drop_cols=["X", "Z"])
```

## EDIT 2:

If you add inplace = True, the object returned in Nonetype, and nothing is stored in subset_df. check the syntax as well. Final function in Edit 1 works.
Hope this helps :)